# How to find a specific string and take it as an entry to a new find in the same file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

1. I need to find a string into many files at multiples folders with a regular expression. The string can be in multiple files.
2. When I find it, take the string and search again in the same file but now with the specific string.
3. And to return the name of the file where the string was found and the string itself.

Think about doing with grep command to find the string and then looping the output but anybody has any idea to solve it better?

### for example:

> Look in file.js the pattern regex: **SearchMethod\(([a-zA-Z] *)\)**
>
> Once found, look for the previous capture at the same file with another regex **capture=('[a-zA-Z']')** and will find something like the following:
>
> From **capture='value';**
>
> get the string **'value'**.
>
> And return the **string 'value'** and the **name of file** to which it belongs.

Comment: you know the file you want to search? Because you say "in a file". And if in a directory, then search for the string ,found via regex, in that particular file itself where the string was found? There could be mulitple matches. Please elaborate.

Comment: Why search the file twice? Once you've used regex to find the string, why not output it then? Or are you looking for line numbers or something?

Comment: This question REALLY needs a sample file with sample search strings. Please provide.

Answer (score 1):

First, some sample data:

```
$ cat file
capture='foo'
capture='bar'
capture='baz'
capture='foobar'
SearchMethod(foo)
SearchMethod(bar)
SearchMethod(qux)
```

Then, get the "search strings", the SearchMethod parameters

```
$ search_strings=$( grep -oP 'SearchMethod\(\K\w+' file | paste -s -d'|' )
$ echo "$search_strings"
foo|bar|qux
```

Then, search for the "capture" words, with the filename in the output

```
$ grep -HoP "capture='\\K($search_strings)\\b" file
file:foo
file:bar
```

The `\b` gives you a word-boundary constraint, which is why `foobar` does not show up in the final output.
Requires GNU grep, which you get on Linux.